# When to use Flux (etc.) with React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux, react-redux

I've been working on a fairly simple React app as a learning process, and want to begin incorporating Flux (or, more likely, Redux) to continue the education.

The code to implement a Flux-alike solution seems *fairly* straightforward, but I'm a little unclear on when it's appropriate and how things should be arranged in a best-practice sense.

In ultra layman terms, my best guess at a common use case is that Flux allows components to talk to each other without having common props passed around, so with that in mind, here's an example of something I would hope to use Flux for in my app:

Let's say I have a user profile component which periodically refreshes via an ajax call. While this call is waiting for its data to be returned, a loading spinner gif displays elsewhere on the page - not in a parent or child of the component that fires the ajax call. In this scenario, how would I use Flux to prompt the spinner to display/hide at the appropriate moments (i.e. begin with the request is sent, end when a response is received)? If its visibility were defined by the profile component's state, that's easy, but obviously I need one component to communicate with what I suppose you could call a distant cousin.

How would I lay out my actions, reducers and whatnot to achieve this?

I'm not looking for anyone to write code for me here, as I'll definitely learn that better by doing it, but I'd definitely appreciate some general advice on the methodology to be used in such a situation.

Many thanks!

Comment: 1. Using Redux as a means of having structured way of your components to remain decoupled yet interact with each other is an excellent use case of redux.
2. Personal opinion: Having moved from Flux to Redux for a small application of mine, I no longer know why one would want to use Flux.
I think the [redux docs/tutorial](http://redux.js.org/) other wise answers all your questions admirably, so I won't go into any more details here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461229/why-use-redux-over-facebook-flux

Comment: The beauty of Flux/Redux is that it is a consistent pattern to manage data *no matter what you're using it for*.  Get a feel for how Redux works and try to implement it without your specific usecase in mind.  Once you have the pattern in place, pulling the data for *any* need will be a simple process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redux basically gives you global state that any component can hook into.

So for your ajax call you'd have 3 actions. Check out [the Redux docs for creating async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

```
GET_USER_PROFILE_START
GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS
GET_USER_PROFILE_ERROR
```

Then you'll have reducers for

```
userProfile
isUserProfileLoading
```

When you fire your ajax request, your async action will first fire your `GET_USER_PROFILE_START` action, which will be picked up by your `isUserProfileLoading` reducer and will set `isUserProfileLoading` to `true`.

Then when the request comes back, if it succeeds, it'll fire `GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS` with a payload of `userProfile`. Your `userProfile` reducer will receive `userProfile` and set it into state.

Your `isUserProfileLoading` reducer will also be listening for `GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS` and will set `isUserProfileLoading` back to `false` when it sees that action.

If your request fails, you fire a `GET_USER_PROFILE_ERROR` action with an `error` payload and do some sort of notification in the UI. And your `isUserProfileLoading` reducer will also be listening for `GET_USER_PROFILE_ERROR` and will also set `isUserProfileLoading` back to `false` when it sees it.

Now any component in your app, no matter where it is on the page or in the component hierarchy, can look at `isUserProfileLoading` and render a loading spinner if it's set to `true`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's exactly the kind of walkthrough I was looking for.