# Why singleton Store in Flux can cause issue for server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, serverside-javascript, isomorphic-javascript

I was reading the following sources [Why use Redux over Facebook Flux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461229/why-use-redux-over-facebook-flux), the redux documentation http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html as well as the definition of a singleton. Could someone explain how the store being a singleton in Flux causes problems for server-side rendering using Flux architecture with react?

Answer (score 1):

Singleton are classes which can be instantiated once. On client-side, each user will have its own store but on the server there will be 1 instance of the store shared for all users....where we need an instance for every request.

e.g: if i have a cart where i got only one item, on serve-side, the store will have 1 item and all users will share the store and state in it.

Here is an answer

https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/facebook-flux-singleton-store-and-server-side-rendering/5652