# React Redux: How to share data between reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a basic todo list. The todo input field for the todo list has an onChange event that triggers an action and sends event.target.value to a reducer and stores each character the users types to a property of the store object.

When the user submits the form I want to get the data that was previously stored via the onChange event, then I want to place it on a new property on the store object.

How do I get data that was previously entered from the store and pull it into a different reducer?

In all the examples I've seen, reducers start with an "initial state". I don't want that, I want the previous state that the user entered.

Below is a CodeSandbox version of the code (for some reason the orange-beige tab to the right needs to be switch to the left to blue for it to render the form. If you don't do that it won't work).

https://codesandbox.io/s/pwqlmp357j

Comment: Please write the code in SO itself because in future, link can break.

Answer (score 7):

> Ask yourself whether you've structured your reducers correctly. If a
>   and b are not independent of one another, why are they separate
>   reducers?

Well if we talk about correctly structuring the reducer, `cachedInput` and `todoList` should live in single reducer. There is no need to create another reducer. Also I guess you need to grab the input value all at once(when user clicks on submit) and send it to store.

If still you want to create seperate reducers then you can follow the approach given below :

Answer to **How to access or share data already in store, inside the reducers?**

**Don't use combineReducers.**

**Example**

replace this code

```
export const a = combineReducers({
  cachInput,
  newTodo
});
```

with

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    cachInput: cachInput(state.app, action, state),
    newTodo: newTodo(state.posts, action, state),
  };
};
```

reducer would be like

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action, root) => {....}
```

and you can access the previous state from `root`

Answer (score 2):

> onChange event that triggers an action and sends event.target.value to a reducer and stores each character the users types to a property of the store object

Practically, this is not right way to use to `redux->action->reducers->store`  considering you are submitting the form to send the same data to reducers.

This will caused un-necessary rendering of component connected with [`redux#connect`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) if you have not handled [`shouldComponentUpdate /componetWillRecieve/getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) nicely

Instead store the each character/string that you typed, inside component `state` and once the user submit it, `dispatch` the `action` to pass the string/characters to `reducer's`.

Comment: I read that if you use Redux you are not supposed to use component state. I guess I am unclear on what the guidelines are.But yes, this makes sense

Comment: No, you can use local state alongside with Redux. This is a good example actually where you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different state(or say initialState) for each reducer. Hence update in one object is not reflecting in the other.

You need to use the shared initialState for both of the reducer and your problem is solved.

You can keep initialState in different file and you can import in both the reducers.

Consider below code sample:

1.InitialState.js

```
export default initialState = {
  todoList: [
    { text: "fake todo" },
    { text: "fake todo" },
    { text: "fake todo" }
  ],
  cachedInput: ""
};
```

2.Now in CachDataOfTodoInput.js

```
import initialState from "InitialState";

export function cachInput(state = initialState, action)
```

3.Same in SubmitDataToTodo.js

```
import initialState from "InitialState";
export function submitNewTodo(state = initialState, action)
```

Hence intialState is shared between your reducers and you will be able to access data in each reducer.

Comment: The initial state in my code for the data I initially cache is empty string. If I import that into the other reducer the data the user types will be lost and replaced with empty string. If you think I am misunderstanding you I can't understand unless I see a code example.

Comment: This seems like it will work but still not clear if it is the correct practice etc:"You can keep initialState in different file and you can import in both the reducers."

Comment: It is the correct practice in redux. Main difference between flux and redux is that flux can have multiple stores while in redux you must declare single store.

Go through this question's answer to know the difference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461229/why-use-redux-over-facebook-flux?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Agree with Hriday, redux should have one store.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion and when I submit todos they are blank. The cachedData is not stored in the other object property.   Example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/6z8vno7vo3

Comment: You have not impmorted initialState in CachDataOfTodoInput.js. Please test the code properly.

Comment: On my local machine it doesn't work....I updated the problem in the online app now the content doesn't render. https://codesandbox.io/s/187z1m6n93

Comment: Sorry the app isn't saving my changes. Here:   https://codesandbox.io/s/wq1nvjz3wk

Comment: You are not returning new objects from the reducers. Is this considered bad?

Comment: Yes you are correct, we should return new objects from the reducers. It is the best practice to write in this way, it helps to maintain immutability on store data. Immutable.js also takes care of the same thing internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your application with initial state that contains previously cached data and if you are using client side rendering, you may insert cached data in redux store into local storage and use that as initial state.

If you just want data to be imported to the other reducer after form submission, you may use redux-thunk. It lets you load current state in your submit action and pass the catches values into the other reducer and store them.

if you are using ssr and you want data be loaded on server there is no way unless saving data on server ( in a file or database), read the data when request is received on server and update your redux store. It will load data all over your app.